# Export Maven3 project from one eclipse instance to another

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3, m2eclipse

I have created a Maven3 web project in eclipse STS (maven-archetype-webapp).

Now I'd like to carry around that project between two machines by just exporting it from eclipse and importing it into eclipse on the other machine.
 
My aim is to have a perfect clone of the project under development with all its sources in my eclipse IDE on the other machine, so that I can just go on working.

With ordinary Java EE web apps I've always imported and exported a war-file.
With the maven project I'm losing the pom-file and my dependancies doing it like that.
Using "maven package" from the command-line I still loose the pom and get the depenencies carried along in the war as jars. I'd prefer to have it the other way round, keeping the pom-file and having new dependencies downloaded into the local repository on the target-machine.
On the other hand just copying the project's workspace-directory to the target machine I got maven dependency issues.

Of course I might be able to tweak the desired behaviour out by elaborate configurations of packaging parameters in the pom-file, but there must be a more straight-forward way than that ...

So what is the simplest way to just clone a maven3 project in eclipse to another instance of eclipse, ideally from within the IDE?

Comment: isnt adding this project to git or mercurial and cloning it, not an option?

Comment: Well, might be an option, but I thought of a very basic solution using eclipse that I can carry on a usb-stick.

Comment: I can't see how it could be easier than executing "git clone" :)

Comment: Well, sounds convenient indeed :-) ... still I would have to work myself into git again (I'm not exactly a pro) where I simply would like move my project from one installation of eclipse to another ...

Comment: File->Import->General->Existing Project Into Workspace. Point to origin workspace, select projects you want to add to current workspace and confirm.

Comment: @BigMike: Thanks !!! - That works out perfectly. I just zip the project's directory outside of Eclipse and import the zip as described ... no dependeny errors this time!

Comment: I use the same when my workspace corrupts.

Comment: @BigMike: Expot & import work perfectly that way, howevwer I have a new problem: Trying to add new dependencies via the pom-file-editor->dependencies->add I don't get any suggestions from the remote mvn-repositories any more when I enter a filter-term (only suggestions from the local .m2 directory) ... I deleted .m2, the sts program-directory and the workspace .metadata ... it won't work again ... ???

Comment: sorry I don't know a thing about MAVEN, import/export simply clones two eclipse project between workspaces (with all metadata and config).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is, as BigMike said, to just copy the project folder to a USB flash drive, copy it onto target computer and import it into local Eclipse workspace via *Import Existing Projects into Workspace*. But copying large number of small files to a USB flash drive (or anywhere else) takes more time then copying one large ZIP file.

And Eclipse already has that functionality :-)

To package the project right click on it (project root) and *Export...* > *General* > *Archive File* > *Next* > specify the file name and click *Finish*.

On the receiving side do *File* > *Import...* > *General* > *Archive File* > *Next* > select the file and click *Finish*.

Comment: Expot & import work perfectly that way, howevwer I have a new problem now: Trying to add new dependencies via the pom-file-editor->dependencies->add I don't get any suggestions from the remote mvn-repositories any more when I enter a filter-term (only suggestions from the local .m2 directory are displayed) ... I've deleted .m2, the whole sts program-directory and the workspace's .metadata ... it just won't work again ... ???

Comment: I am not sure that m2e queries the public repository. In all this time I have worked with it I got only the packages that I already used, i.e. those in my local cache/repository.

Answer (score 4):

The safe and easiest method would be, I guess, creating an archive file of the project (tar, zip...).

But... why not using a SCM to keep your source safe?

Comment: How would I create an scm in eclipse then?

Comment: Eclipse has several providers for source control management systems (Git, Subversion...). You may use the one you want.

Juste use Team > Share from context menu for your project.